# Laravel eloquent: Save data with relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I created an invoice form which has a section where users can dynamically add (via jquery row add) items to be invoiced. 
I need to save these data into two tables: `Invoice and Invoiceitems`. The two tables have `one to many` via MySQL relationship and Laravel models have `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relation assigned.

My question is how to save the data into `Invoiceitems` table.

Comment: You can do that by coding.

Comment: @mycloud welcome to stackoverflow sir. please have a look at question asking policy : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `App\Invoice`, define your relationship with `App\InvoiceItem` as follows:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InvoiceItem::class); 
}
```

In your `App\InvoiceItem` model, define your relationship with `App\Invoice` as follows:

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(InvoiceItem::class); 
}
```

To create an Invoice with many InvoiceItem, you would then do something like this:

```
$invoice->items()->saveMany([
    new App\InvoiceItem(['title' => 'iPhone X']),
]);
```

Read more about [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method).

Comment: Thank you for your reply it worked. I catch all rows from blade. Users generate dynamically rows via JQuery and I marked the input fields like name='txtInvoiceProductUnit[]'